# Log in as different users in backend front end at the same time?

Tags: control-panel, admin, frontend, login

Is it possible be logged in with different users in frontend and backend, and if so, how do I do that?

It would be very convenient being able to test logging in/out different users in frontend, without it affecting the logged in admin user in backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "incognito mode" in your browser, or you use another browser or computer for this type of front end testing.

Comment: You can use incognito mode in Chrome for this.